# CodeSigning - Renewed Certificate Tripping the SmartScreen

Tags: ssl-certificate, smartscreen

We deployed a one-click App (C#/.Net) to the local network around a year ago and using a Commodo Code Signing Certificate had zero problems.

The certificate expired a couple of weeks ago so we renewed it, deleted the old cert from Visual Studio (2017 Pro), imported the new certificate and compiled for a new update, published in exactly the same way we've been doing for the last year.

However, when users update this app (and all others we've written) it's tripping the Windows 10 "SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting" dialog so users are calling support.

When we click on 'more info' it's correctly showing the publisher's name from the certificate.

I called Commodo who were completely unhelpful and said it's a "Microsoft problem" and there is nothing they or we can do about it, which makes a very expensive certificate worthless.

I also looked online and saw other people were also running into this problem but can't find any solutions.

1) Is there anything I could have done wrong in vS2017 when replacing the certificate?

2) Is there anything I can do to 'fix it' to prevent every single employee's PC displaying this dialog every time we do an update for our signed app?

The app is deployed to an SBS 2011 server on the local network and is installed from  \\192.168.0.250\Install\Setup.exe  (this is what the network admin wanted).